# Тест числа на простоту

Tags: алгоритм

Подскажите, простенький тест числа на простоту, пожалуйста. Лучше со ссылками и примерами. Генерируется большое число и надо его проверить является ли оно простым.

П.С. Вообще-то мне задали полиномиальный тест (он же тест АКС - Агравала-Каяла-Саксены), но он какой-то сложный и будет очень медленным, т.к. число хранится в строке. Да и литературы по нему понятной я не нашел.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша, Попробуйте задать вопрос на [Математике](http://math.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал о таком разделе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если число небольшое (скажем 32 разряда) и это именно единичный тест на простоту, а не поиск простых чисел, то IMHO берите лобовое решение (ищите делители).

Например тестирование числа  2147483543 (оно простое) у меня заняло 0.112 clocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac < 2) {
  Usg:;
    fprintf (stderr,"Usage: a.out positiveNumber\n");
    exit (-1);
  }

  int n = atoi(av[1]);
  if (n <= 0)
    n = INT32_MAX+n;
  int start = clock();
  if (n == 1 || n == 2 || n == 3) {
  Prime:;
    printf ("Prime %d clocks\n",clock()-start);
    exit (0);
  }
  if (n%2 == 0) {
  NoPrime:;
    printf ("Not prime %d clocks\n",clock()-start);
    exit (1);
  }
  double dn = n;
  int  lim = sqrt(dn);

  printf ("test %d lim = %d lim^2 = %d\n",n,lim,lim*lim);

  int j;

  for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
  int i; 
  for (i = 3; i <= lim; i += 2) {  // собственно цикл тестирования 
    if (n%i == 0)
      goto NoPrime;
  }

  }
  goto Prime;

}

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ gcc t.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ ./a -102
test 2147483545 lim = 46340 lim^2 = 2147395600
Not prime 0 clocks
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ ./a -104
test 2147483543 lim = 46340 lim^2 = 2147395600
Prime 112 clocks
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $
```

Intel i5-2500 3.30 GHz

Comment: А если число очень большое, то и распараллелить тест можно.