# Числа Кармайкла и тест Соловея-Штрассена

Tags: математика, шифрование

Здравствуйте. Назрел вопрос, по поводу чисел Кармайкла. По сути это составные числа, которые проходят тест Ферма (тест на простоту) и чтоб на них не попасться в шифре RSA, нужно проверить число тестом Соловея-Штрассена, который определяет эти числа (Числа Кармайкла)
Вопрос в следующем: Как тест Соловея-Штрассена определяет число Кармайкла, не могу понять алгоритм. Объясните, пожалуйста, на примере числа 561 (первое число Кармайкла)

Comment: На портале есть раздел математики https://mathematica.stackexchange.com, там есть ответ https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46636/is-there-a-primeq-whose-accuracy-guarantee-you-can-adjust/92857 Здесь раздел программирования, а не математики. Русской версии раздела математики пока нету.

Comment: @nick_n_a а алгоритм шифрования не относится к программированию?

Comment: "Объясните, пожалуйста, на примере числа 561" это относится именно к математике, а касательно программирования, есть много готовых библиотек шифрования, и как минимум, вам нужно указать язык программирования, потому как для каждого свои библиотеки. Возможно вы пытаетесь повторить то что уже реализовано библиотеками.

Comment: @nick_n_a мне бы только эту часть, как он определяет, на сайте с теорией не могу понять(((

Comment: Может вас интерисует вообще [Тест числа на простоту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/63845/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83)?

Comment: @nick_n_a нет, только понять как работает

Comment: @nick_n_a, это не там математика, которая математика, там вопросы именно по [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)